# Nodejs cors allow all origins for certain routes

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have a Node.js backend using express that only allows requests coming from a specific origin (let's call it `localhost:8998`). I'd like to create a public API for the backend, however, authorized with a token rather than by the origin.

Is it even possible to create these kind of routes?

I was thinking of going about this by setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to whatever the request's origin when the request's route is one of the public API routes. Something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var origin = req.get('origin');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Seems like I'm going against the original intentions of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Wanted to hear your guys' thoughts on this/how I should go about implementing a public API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make middlewares:

```
const allowCORS = function(req, res, next) {
    var origin = req.get('origin');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
};

const allowAllIfAuthorized = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthorized) {
    return allowAll(req, res, next);
  } 
  next();
};

const allowedTokens = [...];
const isAuthorized = function(req, res, next) {
  req.isAuthorized = (
    req.query.accessToken 
    && allowedTokens.includes(req.query.accessToken)
  );
  next();
}
```

and attach in certain routes:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));

app.use(
  '/api', 
  allowCORS, // allow cors for public api
  require('./api'));

app.use(
  '/private/api', 
  isAuthorized, allowCORSIfAuthorized, // allow cors if user authorized
  require('./private/api'));
```

> I'd like to create a public API for the backend, however, authorized with a token rather than by the origin.

so it's should be cors all rule everywhere, You're preventing from private access using access tokens which authorized users will have.

**Summary**: CORS is not firewall (gatekeeper) from unauthorized users